# System.JSONException: Apex Type unsupported in JSON: Object

Tags: apex, visualforce, rest-api, json, parser

I was trying to parse json to apex but i was getting

> System.JSONException: Apex Type unsupported in JSON: Object

My apex code was

```java
    public class patdetils77
    {
      
        //public String strBody{ get; set; }
        //public List<PatientDetail> lstopwrpr{get;set;}
        //public List<patient__c> patlistchld{ get; set;}
        //public List<patient__c> patlistSerlz{ get; set;}
    
        public DeviceInfo deviceInfo;
        public DispenseDetail dispenseDetail;
        public List<MedicationList> medicationList;
        public MiscellaneousDetail miscellaneousDetail;
        public PatientDetail patientDetail;
        public ProductDetail productDetail;
        public List<SmartVisitList> smartVisitList;
        public TrainingDetail trainingDetail;
    
           public patdetils77 ()
           {
                //patlistchld= new list<patient__c>();
               //patlistSerlz= new list<patient__c>();
           }
    
    
         public class PatientDetail {
            public String Address;
            public String BlueStarID;
            public Object CellphoneNumber;
            public String DOB;
            public String Email;
            public String Gender;
            public Object HomephoneNumber;
            public String HubCode;
            public Boolean IsMobileUser;
            public Boolean IsVTCompleted;
            public String Name;
            public Object SamleCode;
            public String WorkphoneNumber;
        }
    
        public class DispenseDetail {
            public Boolean IsRespondedToRefillPrompt;
            public String LastFillDate;
            public String LastUsageDate;
            public Integer NumOfRefillsLeft;
            public Integer NumOfRefillsPrescribed;
            public String PayerType;
            public String RespondedDate;
            public String RxExpirationDate;
            public String RxID;
        }
    
        public class TrainingDetail {
            public Object TrainerName;
            public String TrainingDate;
            public Object TrainingStatus;
        }
    
        public class ProductDetail {
            public Object HubStatus;
            public Object PharmacyStatus;
            public Object ProductStatus;
            public String RegistrationDate;
            public String SRFCompletedDate;
            public String SRFRecievedDate;
            public Object SRFStatus;
            public String TrainingCompletedDate;
            public Object TrainingStatus;
        }
    
    
        public class SmartVisitList {
            public String DeliverStatus;
            public String DeliveryDateTime;
            public String FaxNumber;
            public Integer NumOfSV;
            public String TriggeredDateTime;
        }
    
        public class MiscellaneousDetail {
            public String DateOfPTR;
            public Boolean IsAccountLocked;
            public Boolean IsPTR;
            public String LastMobileLogin;
            public String LastWebLogin;
            public Integer NumOfFailedLoginAttempts;
        }
    
        public class DeviceInfo {
            public Integer BuildID;
            public String MakeModel;
            public String MobileMake;
            public String Version;
        }
    
        public class MedicationList {
            public Integer Dosage;
            public Object Frequency;
            public String MedicationName;
            public String Strength;
        }
    
    
        public static patdetils77 parse(String json)
        {
            return (patdetils77)System.JSON.deserialize(json,patdetils77.class);
        }
    
        public PageReference gettingrecords()
         {
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setHeader('Content-Length', '0');
            req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            req.setEndpoint('https://dev1-dsm.testwd.com/CRMPOC/PatientProfileService.svc/GetPatientCompleteData');
            req.setMethod('POST');
            
            //Set patient ExternalID
            req.setBody('"S0110010021"');
            
            Http http = new Http();
            req.setTimeout(60000);
            system.debug('req***************'+req);
            HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
            String strBody= res.getBody();
            system.debug('response------------'+strBody);
            
            
            patdetils77 objPant = parse(strBody);   
            
            system.debug('response---par---------'+objPant);
            
            
            
            
            /*
            
            for(PatientDetail objPRWrp:lstopwrpr)
            {
                patient__c objPant = new patient__c();
                
                objPant.BlueStarID__c = objPRWrp.BlueStarID;
                objPant.Name = objPRWrp.Name;
               // objPant.Hub_Code__c= objPRWrp.HubCode;
                objPant.Gender__c= objPRWrp.Gender;
                objPant.Mobile_User__c= objPRWrp.IsMobileUser;
               // objPant.SampleCode__c= objPRWrp.SamleCode;
                objPant.IsVTCompleted__c= objPRWrp.IsVTCompleted;
                objPant.Email__c= objPRWrp.Email;
                objPant.Address__c= objPRWrp.Address;
                patlistchld.add(objPant);
            }
                    system.debug('patlist-----'+patlistchld);*/
               
            
            return null;
        } 
        
        
    
    
    }
```

and my json was

```json
    {
       "deviceInfo":{
          "BuildID":87,
          "MakeModel":"Apple_iPhone",
          "MobileMake":"Apple_iPhone",
          "Version":"2.4"
       },
       "dispenseDetail":{
          "IsRespondedToRefillPrompt":true,
          "LastFillDate":"\/Date(1426046400000-0400)\/",
          "LastUsageDate":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/",
          "NumOfRefillsLeft":1,
          "NumOfRefillsPrescribed":1,
          "PayerType":"1",
          "RespondedDate":"\/Date(1426126039530-0400)\/",
          "RxExpirationDate":"\/Date(1455080400000-0500)\/",
          "RxID":"ngpX6g+iF05m2yuSN9KeN8s+kKCGQPdrOIC8b+zuSic="
       },
       "medicationList":[
          {
             "Dosage":15,
             "Frequency":null,
             "MedicationName":"Victoza 3-Pak",
             "Strength":"0.6 mg\/0.1 mL"
          },
          {
             "Dosage":1,
             "Frequency":"1",
             "MedicationName":"glipizide-metformin",
             "Strength":"2.5-250"
          },
          {
             "Dosage":1,
             "Frequency":null,
             "MedicationName":"Marinol",
             "Strength":"2.5"
          },
          {
             "Dosage":1,
             "Frequency":"1",
             "MedicationName":"DermaMed (aluminum hydroxide)",
             "Strength":""
          },
          {
             "Dosage":2,
             "Frequency":"1",
             "MedicationName":"metformin",
             "Strength":"500"
          },
          {
             "Dosage":3,
             "Frequency":"1",
             "MedicationName":"metformin",
             "Strength":"500"
          },
          {
             "Dosage":1,
             "Frequency":"1",
             "MedicationName":"metformin",
             "Strength":"500"
          },
          {
             "Dosage":2,
             "Frequency":"1,32",
             "MedicationName":"Acanya",
             "Strength":"1.2-2.5"
          },
          {
             "Dosage":2,
             "Frequency":"1",
             "MedicationName":"Effient",
             "Strength":"5"
          },
          {
             "Dosage":3,
             "Frequency":"1",
             "MedicationName":"Effient",
             "Strength":"5"
          },
          {
             "Dosage":2,
             "Frequency":null,
             "MedicationName":"magnesium oxide",
             "Strength":"400"
          },
          {
             "Dosage":2,
             "Frequency":"1",
             "MedicationName":"Amaryl",
             "Strength":"1"
          },
          {
             "Dosage":2,
             "Frequency":"1",
             "MedicationName":"aspirin",
             "Strength":"325"
          },
          {
             "Dosage":32,
             "Frequency":"1",
             "MedicationName":"Ayr Sinus Rinse",
             "Strength":""
          },
          {
             "Dosage":32,
             "Frequency":"1",
             "MedicationName":"Ayr Sinus Rinse",
             "Strength":""
          },
          {
             "Dosage":2,
             "Frequency":"1",
             "MedicationName":"Keralyt",
             "Strength":"3"
          },
          {
             "Dosage":15,
             "Frequency":"1",
             "MedicationName":"Apidra",
             "Strength":"100"
          },
          {
             "Dosage":15,
             "Frequency":"1",
             "MedicationName":"Apidra",
             "Strength":"100"
          },
          {
             "Dosage":15,
             "Frequency":"1",
             "MedicationName":"Apidra",
             "Strength":"100"
          },
          {
             "Dosage":10.5,
             "Frequency":"1",
             "MedicationName":"Humalog",
             "Strength":"100"
          },
          {
             "Dosage":10.5,
             "Frequency":"1",
             "MedicationName":"Humalog",
             "Strength":"100"
          },
          {
             "Dosage":10.5,
             "Frequency":"1",
             "MedicationName":"Humalog",
             "Strength":"100"
          }
       ],
       "miscellaneousDetail":{
          "DateOfPTR":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/",
          "IsAccountLocked":false,
          "IsPTR":false,
          "LastMobileLogin":"\/Date(1426323602323-0400)\/",
          "LastWebLogin":"\/Date(1426764614690-0400)\/",
          "NumOfFailedLoginAttempts":0
       },
       "patientDetail":{
          "Address":"#1. WellDoc Software Pvt ltd . Brigade Software park - 1 Unit 501,5th floor,B Block,No 42, Banglore ",
          "BlueStarID":"S0110010021",
          "CellphoneNumber":null,
          "DOB":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/",
          "Email":"crm+hubpat1@welldocinc.com",
          "Gender":"M",
          "HomephoneNumber":null,
          "HubCode":"S0110010021",
          "IsMobileUser":false,
          "IsVTCompleted":true,
          "Name":"FirstName1 LastName1",
          "SamleCode":null,
          "WorkphoneNumber":"9876543211"
       },
       "productDetail":{
          "HubStatus":null,
          "PharmacyStatus":null,
          "ProductStatus":null,
          "RegistrationDate":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/",
          "SRFCompletedDate":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/",
          "SRFRecievedDate":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/",
          "SRFStatus":null,
          "TrainingCompletedDate":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/",
          "TrainingStatus":null
       },
       "smartVisitList":[
          {
             "DeliverStatus":"3",
             "DeliveryDateTime":"\/Date(1378135864987-0400)\/",
             "FaxNumber":"14436923099",
             "NumOfSV":17,
             "TriggeredDateTime":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/"
          },
          {
             "DeliverStatus":"3",
             "DeliveryDateTime":"\/Date(1378342865663-0400)\/",
             "FaxNumber":"14436923099",
             "NumOfSV":17,
             "TriggeredDateTime":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/"
          },
          {
             "DeliverStatus":"3",
             "DeliveryDateTime":"\/Date(1380297673573-0400)\/",
             "FaxNumber":"14436923099",
             "NumOfSV":17,
             "TriggeredDateTime":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/"
          },
          {
             "DeliverStatus":"3",
             "DeliveryDateTime":"\/Date(1380756857163-0400)\/",
             "FaxNumber":"14436923099",
             "NumOfSV":17,
             "TriggeredDateTime":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/"
          },
          {
             "DeliverStatus":"3",
             "DeliveryDateTime":"\/Date(1382094075263-0400)\/",
             "FaxNumber":"14436923099",
             "NumOfSV":17,
             "TriggeredDateTime":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/"
          },
          {
             "DeliverStatus":"3",
             "DeliveryDateTime":"\/Date(1382106677580-0400)\/",
             "FaxNumber":"14436923099",
             "NumOfSV":17,
             "TriggeredDateTime":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/"
          },
          {
             "DeliverStatus":"3",
             "DeliveryDateTime":"\/Date(1382958065347-0400)\/",
             "FaxNumber":"14436923099",
             "NumOfSV":17,
             "TriggeredDateTime":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/"
          },
          {
             "DeliverStatus":"3",
             "DeliveryDateTime":"\/Date(1382968864730-0400)\/",
             "FaxNumber":"14436923099",
             "NumOfSV":17,
             "TriggeredDateTime":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/"
          },
          {
             "DeliverStatus":"3",
             "DeliveryDateTime":"\/Date(1393283482053-0500)\/",
             "FaxNumber":"14436923099",
             "NumOfSV":17,
             "TriggeredDateTime":"\/Date(1378324800000-0400)\/"
          },
          {
             "DeliverStatus":"3",
             "DeliveryDateTime":"\/Date(1393296082523-0500)\/",
             "FaxNumber":"14436923099",
             "NumOfSV":17,
             "TriggeredDateTime":"\/Date(1380279780000-0400)\/"
          },
          {
             "DeliverStatus":"3",
             "DeliveryDateTime":"\/Date(1393290682680-0500)\/",
             "FaxNumber":"14436923099",
             "NumOfSV":17,
             "TriggeredDateTime":"\/Date(1380739800000-0400)\/"
          },
          {
             "DeliverStatus":"3",
             "DeliveryDateTime":"\/Date(1393288882960-0500)\/",
             "FaxNumber":"14436923099",
             "NumOfSV":17,
             "TriggeredDateTime":"\/Date(1382110840343-0400)\/"
          },
          {
             "DeliverStatus":"3",
             "DeliveryDateTime":"\/Date(1393292483040-0500)\/",
             "FaxNumber":"14436923099",
             "NumOfSV":17,
             "TriggeredDateTime":"\/Date(1382090346343-0400)\/"
          },
          {
             "DeliverStatus":"3",
             "DeliveryDateTime":"\/Date(1393285284500-0500)\/",
             "FaxNumber":"14436923099",
             "NumOfSV":17,
             "TriggeredDateTime":"\/Date(1382975180957-0400)\/"
          },
          {
             "DeliverStatus":"3",
             "DeliveryDateTime":"\/Date(1393287083297-0500)\/",
             "FaxNumber":"14436923099",
             "NumOfSV":17,
             "TriggeredDateTime":"\/Date(1382986463627-0400)\/"
          },
          {
             "DeliverStatus":"3",
             "DeliveryDateTime":"\/Date(1409395687970-0400)\/",
             "FaxNumber":"14436923099",
             "NumOfSV":17,
             "TriggeredDateTime":"\/Date(1409379360000-0400)\/"
          },
          {
             "DeliverStatus":"4",
             "DeliveryDateTime":"\/Date(1421914133400-0500)\/",
             "FaxNumber":"14436923099",
             "NumOfSV":17,
             "TriggeredDateTime":"\/Date(1421868600000-0500)\/"
          }
       ],
       "trainingDetail":{
          "TrainerName":null,
          "TrainingDate":"\/Date(-62135578800000-0500)\/",
          "TrainingStatus":null
       }
    }
```

Can anyone explain me regarding this issue, as i am completely new to salesfroce.

Any help is highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The Salesforce `JSON.deserialize(String, Type)` method cannot deserialize from JSON into generic `Object`, or into objects with generic `Object` fields, it can only deserialize into concrete types with fields that have concrete type.

Everywhere the you have defined your field types as `Object`, e.g. `public Object CellphoneNumber`, you need to replace `Object` with the appropriate data type, i.e. `String`, `Integer`, etc.

Once you have replaced all of the `Object` fields in your data structures you should be able to deserialize your JSON into them successfully.

PS. It looks like you've used JSON2Apex to generate this. The reason the types of these fields are `Object` and not the correct types is because their values are `null`. JSON2Apex doesn't guess what type a `null` object should be (and rightly so), which is why it has used `Object` for these types.

Answer (score 1):

Alex had a great answer. Also though something to note is you can use JSON.deserializeUntyped and cast to objects like so:

```
Map<String, Object> payloadMessage = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(request.requestBody.toString());
```

I used this when I had a JSON map with a list and string alongside each other. The JSON I was converting looked like this:

```
{ "myStringKey" : "myStringValue", "myListKey" : ["val1", "val2"] }
```

When accessing the string I did:

```
String myString = (String)payloadMessage.get('myStringKey');
```

and when accessing the list of strings I did

```
List<String> myList = (List<String>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(payloadMessage.get('myListKey').toString());
```